# Google Maps just showing a "Google" logo on emulator but working fine on real device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, android-emulator

I saw many people asking "Google map is working on emulator but not on real device".But my case is just opposite of that. I am working on a maps application where I have to track multiple vehicles. I have everything(code) setup but the problem is that I have to create multiple instances of devices to get a feel of multiple devices online simultaneously. But the problem is that map isn't showing up on emulator & it is working fine on real device, it is just showing a google logo in the bottom left corner in emulator. So, what could be the problem?? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Google logo in the bottom means, google set is correctly done, you need to just debug in a listener, what data return in it, either you receive error or success response from google map load.